# SVG to XAML AA Issues?

Tags: wpf, xaml, svg

I'm having an issue after converting a [SVG file](http://files.gamebanana.com/bitpit/mail_icon.svg) to XAML. Here's the XAML code since I can't post more than two links:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ApplicationMain.Icons.Mail"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ApplicationMain.Icons"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="112" d:DesignWidth="132">
<Viewbox >
    <Canvas Width="132.000" Height="112.000">

        <Canvas>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff000000" Data="F1 M 15.000,108.000 L 123.000,108.000 L 123.000,99.000 L 132.000,99.000 L 132.000,18.000 L 123.000,18.000 L 123.000,9.000 L 114.000,9.000 L 114.000,0.000 L 24.000,0.000 L 24.000,9.000 L 15.000,9.000 L 15.000,18.000 L 6.000,18.000 L 6.000,99.000 L 15.000,99.000 L 15.000,108.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffefefef" Data="F1 M 15.000,27.000 L 24.000,27.000 L 24.000,90.000 L 15.000,90.000 L 15.000,27.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff434343" Data="F1 M 15.000,90.000 L 24.000,90.000 L 24.000,99.000 L 15.000,99.000 L 15.000,90.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff434343" Data="F1 M 24.000,81.000 L 33.000,81.000 L 33.000,90.000 L 24.000,90.000 L 24.000,81.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff434343" Data="F1 M 33.000,72.000 L 42.000,72.000 L 42.000,81.000 L 33.000,81.000 L 33.000,72.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff434343" Data="F1 M 42.000,63.000 L 51.000,63.000 L 51.000,72.000 L 42.000,72.000 L 42.000,63.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff434343" Data="F1 M 51.000,54.000 L 60.000,54.000 L 60.000,63.000 L 51.000,63.000 L 51.000,54.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff8d8d8d" Data="F1 M 42.000,45.000 L 51.000,45.000 L 51.000,54.000 L 42.000,54.000 L 42.000,45.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff8d8d8d" Data="F1 M 33.000,36.000 L 42.000,36.000 L 42.000,45.000 L 33.000,45.000 L 33.000,36.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff8d8d8d" Data="F1 M 24.000,27.000 L 33.000,27.000 L 33.000,36.000 L 24.000,36.000 L 24.000,27.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff8d8d8d" Data="F1 M 15.000,18.000 L 24.000,18.000 L 24.000,27.000 L 15.000,27.000 L 15.000,18.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffb2b2b2" Data="F1 M 24.000,36.000 L 33.000,36.000 L 33.000,81.000 L 24.000,81.000 L 24.000,36.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffb2b2b2" Data="F1 M 33.000,45.000 L 42.000,45.000 L 42.000,72.000 L 33.000,72.000 L 33.000,45.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffb2b2b2" Data="F1 M 42.000,54.000 L 51.000,54.000 L 51.000,63.000 L 42.000,63.000 L 42.000,54.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff8d8d8d" Data="F1 M 60.000,63.000 L 78.000,63.000 L 78.000,72.000 L 60.000,72.000 L 60.000,63.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffb2b2b2" Data="F1 M 51.000,63.000 L 60.000,63.000 L 60.000,72.000 L 51.000,72.000 L 51.000,63.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffb2b2b2" Data="F1 M 78.000,63.000 L 87.000,63.000 L 87.000,72.000 L 78.000,72.000 L 78.000,63.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffb2b2b2" Data="F1 M 42.000,72.000 L 96.000,72.000 L 96.000,81.000 L 42.000,81.000 L 42.000,72.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffb2b2b2" Data="F1 M 33.000,81.000 L 105.000,81.000 L 105.000,90.000 L 33.000,90.000 L 33.000,81.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff7e7e7e" Data="F1 M 24.000,90.000 L 114.000,90.000 L 114.000,99.000 L 24.000,99.000 L 24.000,90.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff434343" Data="F1 M 87.000,63.000 L 96.000,63.000 L 96.000,72.000 L 87.000,72.000 L 87.000,63.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff434343" Data="F1 M 96.000,72.000 L 105.000,72.000 L 105.000,81.000 L 96.000,81.000 L 96.000,72.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff434343" Data="F1 M 105.000,81.000 L 114.000,81.000 L 114.000,90.000 L 105.000,90.000 L 105.000,81.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff434343" Data="F1 M 114.000,90.000 L 123.000,90.000 L 123.000,99.000 L 114.000,99.000 L 114.000,90.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffb2b2b2" Data="F1 M 87.000,54.000 L 96.000,54.000 L 96.000,63.000 L 87.000,63.000 L 87.000,54.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffb2b2b2" Data="F1 M 96.000,45.000 L 105.000,45.000 L 105.000,72.000 L 96.000,72.000 L 96.000,45.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffb2b2b2" Data="F1 M 105.000,36.000 L 114.000,36.000 L 114.000,81.000 L 105.000,81.000 L 105.000,36.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff7e7e7e" Data="F1 M 114.000,18.000 L 123.000,18.000 L 123.000,90.000 L 114.000,90.000 L 114.000,18.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff8d8d8d" Data="F1 M 87.000,45.000 L 96.000,45.000 L 96.000,54.000 L 87.000,54.000 L 87.000,45.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff8d8d8d" Data="F1 M 96.000,36.000 L 105.000,36.000 L 105.000,45.000 L 96.000,45.000 L 96.000,36.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff8d8d8d" Data="F1 M 105.000,27.000 L 114.000,27.000 L 114.000,36.000 L 105.000,36.000 L 105.000,27.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff434343" Data="F1 M 78.000,54.000 L 87.000,54.000 L 87.000,63.000 L 78.000,63.000 L 78.000,54.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffffffff" Data="F1 M 60.000,45.000 L 78.000,45.000 L 78.000,54.000 L 60.000,54.000 L 60.000,45.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffffffff" Data="F1 M 51.000,36.000 L 60.000,36.000 L 60.000,45.000 L 51.000,45.000 L 51.000,36.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffffffff" Data="F1 M 42.000,27.000 L 51.000,27.000 L 51.000,36.000 L 42.000,36.000 L 42.000,27.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffffffff" Data="F1 M 33.000,18.000 L 42.000,18.000 L 42.000,27.000 L 33.000,27.000 L 33.000,18.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffffffff" Data="F1 M 24.000,9.000 L 114.000,9.000 L 114.000,18.000 L 24.000,18.000 L 24.000,9.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffffffff" Data="F1 M 96.000,18.000 L 105.000,18.000 L 105.000,27.000 L 96.000,27.000 L 96.000,18.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffffffff" Data="F1 M 87.000,27.000 L 96.000,27.000 L 96.000,36.000 L 87.000,36.000 L 87.000,27.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffffffff" Data="F1 M 78.000,36.000 L 87.000,36.000 L 87.000,45.000 L 78.000,45.000 L 78.000,36.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffd6d6d6" Data="F1 M 42.000,18.000 L 96.000,18.000 L 96.000,27.000 L 42.000,27.000 L 42.000,18.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffd6d6d6" Data="F1 M 51.000,27.000 L 87.000,27.000 L 87.000,36.000 L 51.000,36.000 L 51.000,27.000 Z"/>

            <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ffd6d6d6" Data="F1 M 60.000,36.000 L 78.000,36.000 L 78.000,45.000 L 60.000,45.000 L 60.000,36.000 Z"/>

        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

I am getting an issue with lines showing up between the each path in the XAML. Here's an image to give you an idea.
[XAML AA issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfbzE.png)

Yes, this issue still occurs when I run the program itself. It occurs across different computers and resolutions as well. I'm not sure whether this issue is related to AA or what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: These lines are the result from rounding errors caused by the `ViewBox` while positioning the `Path`s. You can easiely proove that by giving the very first path a different fill color e.g. red. Then the lines turn to red which prooves there are small gaps between the path and the background shines through. Another proove is to remove the `Viewbox` (for the test). I don't think there is a good solution while keeping the current approach.